# Distribution-preserving function of uniform random vectors

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, uniform-distribution, jacobian

Let's say $\mathbf{x}$ is a **uniform** $d$-dimensional random vector, whose support set is $[-1,1]^d$.

Let's say $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is an arbitrary differentiable bijective function, and the random vector $f(\mathbf{x})$ has the same distribution as $\mathbf{x}$.

Can we conclude that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}=0$ if $i \ne j$ ?

**Edited - Additional condition**:

Assume that $f$ is not a coordinate-exchanging function (i.e. $f$ is not a function that only re-permutes different components of $\mathbf{x}$)

Comment: No. By the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables), the transformed distribution density is the old one times the Jacobian of $f$. So all you get with uniform densities is that the Jacobian is $1$, not any conditions on individual derivatives.

Comment: A simple counterexample is a rotation by $\pi/2$ radians.

Comment: @Conifold Well we also need the support to be preserved, so it’s a bit more restricted than that.

Comment: @Milten Thanks for your reply. I added an additional condition to avoid the trivial example that $f$ is a coordinate-exchanging function.

Comment: Rotations do not just permute components, and excluding obvious counterexamples won't help. This is just too far from true.

Comment: I can give a counterexmple that's almost everywhere differentiable. Shirley and Chiu (1997) give an area-preserving homeomoprhism between the unit square and the disk, which is differentiable everywhere except on $y=\pm x$. So map $[-1,1]^2$ to the disk, rotate by any angle, and transform back to $[-1,1]^2$. For an everywhere differentiable function though, I think the corners of the cube have implications that I don't fully know. It may be that corners need to be mapped to corners - I'm not sure.